# Freezing UI and odd thread behavior (WPF)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, caliburn.micro

I am building an application with WPF and C# and I have run into an odd problem. There are multiple threads in my application, many of which are created through System.Timer timers. There is a particular action I can take that will cause the UI of my application to freeze; my UI will freeze permanently when this happens. The oddest thing about this though is that if I check the number of available threads with `Threadpool.GetAvialbaleThreads`, the number of available threads will continuously diminish if I don't stop the application. All of the threads in my application are created either via timer or the `Task.StartNew` method.

There are several parts of my code that spin up new threads, I will try to show all of them here in an abbreviated way.

**DataManager.cs**

```
// Two System.Timers.Timer(s) handle generating data values on 3 second and 1.5 second intervals.
_averageTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000 * 3);
_averageTimer.Elapsed += GenerateNewAveragePoint;
_averageTimer.Enabled = false;

_flowGenTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000 * 1.5);
_flowGenTimer.Elapsed += GenerateNewFlowSet;
_flowGenTimer.Enabled = false;

// I also have a primary work loop in this class which is created via Task
// This function runs continuously
Task.Run(() => ProcessData());

// I also send off a Task to do file I/O about every 3 seconds
Task.Run(() =>
{
    lock (_sharedData.FileLock)
    {  
          _continuousFileManager.WriteDataSubset(tmpData);
    }
});

// Finally, I have a similar file I/O function to the one above, but it is
// called in the timer which fires every 3 seconds
Task.Run(() =>
{
    lock (_sharedData.FileLock)
    {  
          _averageFileManager.WriteDataSubset(tmpData);
    }
});
```

So from this class it appears that I probably utilize a max of 6 threads.

In another class I have 3 calls to Dispatcher.Invoke

**AdvancedPanel.cs**

```
// RealtimeDataFlowItems is an ObservableCollection
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(delegate
{
      RealtimeDataFlowItems.Insert(0, avgFlow);
});

// RealtimeDataHRItems is an ObservableCollection
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(delegate
{
      RealtimeDataHRItems.Insert(0, avgFlow);
});

// RealtimeDataTimeItems is an ObservableCollection
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(delegate
{
      RealtimeDataTimeItems.Insert(0, avgFlow);
});
```

In another class I have one call to Dispatcher.Invoke
**DataInfo.cs**

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(delegate
{
    IndicatorPoints = new PointCollection(new[] { /* Removed for brevity */});
}
```

In another class there are two System.Timers.Timer(s) which execute at intervals of 15 ms and 2 seconds.

**PlotData.cs**

```
_plotTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(15);
_plotTimer.Elapsed += ProcessLoop;
_plotTimer.Enabled = false;

_boundsTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000 * 2);
_boundsTimer.Enabled = false;
_boundsTimer.Elapsed += CheckYAxisBounds;
```

Also, this class utilizes the OxyPlot plotting library in order to present realtime data in the UI. OxyPlot obviously has to modify the UI, so will be performing actions on the UI thread.

As a final note, I use Caliburn.Micro in my application and make use of its EventAggregator heavily. Each time I wish to publish a message a new Task is started with the StartNew method. Nearly all of the classes in my application make use of the EventAggregator in some capacity, so there are several threads that become utilized from these actions.

I hope this information is helpful, please let me know if there is more that I should provide. I am hoping that one of you could provide me any insight on what might be happening, and how I might be able to go about debugging and solving my UI freezing issue. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: ambigous question, put some code how the thread is created and UI calls made from that thread

Comment: We need code and numbers. How many threads did you design for, how many are being created and at what rate?

Comment: Not enough to debug the problem. How can we tell if you're recursively creating threads, e.g.? Try triggering the broken state, breaking the program in a debugger, looking at the Threads window, and seeing what threads are doing.